# Primary with different color combinations

Tags: css, bem

I have a situation where the designers have come up with a design where there is a primary button which have 2 color combinations.

I'm writing my CSS following the principles of BEM and I'm finding it difficult to name the modifiers for this button.

Currently I have a modifier class called `.button--primary` which has one of the two color combinations, however the second color combination should also apply to primary buttons.

Usually I would just make two different modifiers (e.g. `.button--midnight`, `.button--moss`), but currently there is a lot of javascript which attaches functionality to buttons with the class `.button--primary`.

Should I change the `.button--primary` to an element instead (e.g. `button__primary`) and then add the two modifiers that I gave examples of ealier?
Or should I create 2 classes with modifiers on a modifier (e.g. `.button--primary--midnight`, `.button--primary--moss`) instead?

Comment: Can't you use this two modifiers (`.button--midnight` and `.button--moss`) with `.button--primary` class?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to stop you from using multiple classes/modifiers:

`<element class="button button--primary button--midnight" />`
and
 `<element class="button button--primary button--moss" />`

but this has it's disadvantages.

First you clutter your html, and make it less readable. And secondly, using two modifiers, forces the importance of source order in `CSS`, so in this setup, last rule will always win:

```
.button {
  color: black; }

.button--primary {
  color: green; }

.button--moss {
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;  } 

.button--midnight {
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: bold;  }
```

This will force you to remember about this constraint, which itself creates a maintenance problem.

So, it's better to stick to the rule of **NOT** using multiple modifiers, so in your case you could do:
`<element class="button button--primary-midnight" />` and `<element class="button button--primary-moss" />`
and possibly use `SASS` `@extend` for sharing common rules between  `button--primary` and `button--midnight`:

```
//SASS
.button--primary {
  color:white;
  //other rules
} 
.button--primary-midnight {
  @extend .button-primary;
  color:black;
}
```

which will compile to:

```
/* CSS */
.button--primary,
.button--primary-midnight {
  color:white;
  /* other rules */
} 
.button--primary-midnight {
  color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is necessarily how to solve the OP's question as there is not a technical barrier, it is more the appropriate way to solve this.

Firstly there is a code smell in this statement.

> Usually I would just make two different modifiers (e.g. .button--midnight, .button--moss), but currently there is a lot of javascript which attaches functionality to buttons with the class .button--primary.

Because the CSS and JavaScript are tightly coupled one is constrained by the other. Your CSS shouldn't care about JavaScript and vice versa. If you need classes as JavaScript hooks then you should create separate classes, prefixed with `js` e.g.

```
js-button--primary
```

This class should never be used for styling and only for JavaScript.

Secondly, however you choose to solve this in CSS, the important principles to keep in mind are:

1. Is the solution in keeping with the approach for the whole project.
2. Will another developer on the project understand what I have done.

As long the method you choose satisfies those two conditions then it is an appropriate solution.